# Looking for the perfect frame

Tags: disc-brake, commuter, through-axle

I'm looking for the perfect frame for my next build and looking for suggestions. This is going to be a commuter bike. I want disc brakes with thru-axles, a classic  road-ish geometry as much as possible, clearance for wide tires and fenders and a rear rack. Oh and steel is real :) I'm also going to set it up with flat bars and a 1x drivetrain (probably SRAM Rival 1x).

So far, I have:

-All City Gorilla Monsoon

Looks to check all the boxes but very expensive! Also, I read on a review that it was heavy. I'm not sure if this is just coming from someone that's not used to steel bikes or if it really is heavy compared to, say, a Surly frame.

-Black Mountain Cycles Monster Cross Disc (MCD)

Also checks most of the boxes at a better price. The only thing is the geometry is more like a mountain bike than a road bike but IDK if that would work to my advantage with the flat bar setup I'm planning.

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Note that product recommendations are specifically off-topic:  "Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly."

Comment: It seems like most of the non-product-recommendation questions you could reasonably ask, like best posture/geometry/materials for a commuter bike, you've already decided, at which point it's up to you to find an existing product that meets your criteria.

Comment: All steel frames are relatively heavy.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus is correct that steel frames are heavier than carbon or aluminum ones of similar price level. However, almost all riders weigh over 100 lbs, sometimes close to 200lbs. A steel frame will be a penalty of 1-2 lbs. That is not Also, the OP used Surly as a reference point, and I believe all their bikes are steel. Relatively heavy steel, at that.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I note All City specs 612 CroMoly steel for the GM frame. Surely uses 4130 CroMoly on the Cross-Check. I expect those frames are going to come out a bit heavier than say a Gunnar which uses Reynolds or True Temper tube sets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as the "perfect frame." This is why the N+1 rule exists:

> **Rule #12: The correct number of bikes to own is n+1.**
>
> While the minimum number of bikes one should own is three, the correct number is n+1, where n is the number of bikes currently owned. This equation may also be re-written as s-1, where s is the number of bikes owned that would result in separation from your partner.
>
> [Velominati](https://www.velominati.com/#12)